# How do I shrink the text in a GTK+3 active button without changing the whole button size?

Tags: themes, gtk3, button, css

I'm working on a custom GTK+3 theme for Ubuntu 15.10, and one of the effects I want to use for an active (clicked) button is to slightly shrink the text shown on the button for a pressed-in look. The way I've been trying to do this is with something like the following:

```
.button:active {
  font-size: 0.95em;
}
```

This shrinks the text like I want while the button is clicked, but it has the unfortunate side effect of changing the button height as well (presumably to keep the padding constant). How can I get the text inside the button to shrink down slightly while keeping the button size the same?